# How do I split a line of code into two using switch in c#

Tags: c#, split

I have this line of code

```
acctStatusLabel.Text = acct.acctStatusCode == "APPR" || acct.acctStatusCode == "IACT"
                                       ? "Inactive"
                                       : "Closed";
```

What I need to do is change it so the APPR StatusCode shows "Approved" and the IACT StatusCode shows "Inactive"

This is the full code set

```
if (acct.acctStatusCode == "DORM")
            acctStatusLabel.Text = "Dormant";
        else
            acctStatusLabel.Text = acct.acctStatusCode == "APPR" || acct.acctStatusCode == "IACT"
                                       ? "Inactive"
                                       : "Closed";
```

Comment: [Switch reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx)

Comment: Or... you know... you could just Google it. First result: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: New to c# had no idea what I was looking for. Thank's for the link.

Comment: @TheDizzle What? Yes you do, all you had to google is `C# switch`. Try a little harder before posting questions as simple as this.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
switch(acct.acctStatusCode)
{
    case "DORM":
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Dormant";
        break;
    case "APPR":
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Approved";
        break;
    case "IACT":
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Inactive";
        break;
    default:
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Closed";
        break;
}
```

A better option may be to use a static dictionary:

```
{somewhere else}
private static Dictionary<string, string> Codes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

{in static constructor}
Codes.Add("DORM","Dormant");
Codes.Add("APPR","Approved");
Codes.Add("IACT","Inactive");
```

your code would then be something like:

```
// set default value
acctStatusLabel.Text = "Closed";
// lookup decoded value
if(Codes.ContainsKey(code))
    acctStatusLabel.Text = Codes[code];
```

An *even better* way would be to put the codes/decodes in a database table or other data source that can be changed without having to recompile your app.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
switch (acct.acctStatusCode)
{
    case "DORM":
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Dormant";
        break;
    case "APPR":
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Approved";
        break;
    case "IACT":
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Inactive";
        break;
    default:
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Closed";
}
```

**However**, you'd be much better off moving that logic into the `acct` object itself.  Something like this:

```
public string StatusCodeText
{
    get
    {
        switch (acctStatusCode)
        {
            case "DORM":
                return "Dormant";
            case "APPR":
                return "Approved";
            case "IACT":
                return "Inactive";
        }
        return "Closed";
    }
}
```

Then using it becomes a lot simpler:

```
acctStatusLabel.Text = acct.StatusCodeText;
```

"Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around." - Eric S. Raymond

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(acct.acctStatusCode)
{
    case "DORM":
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Dormant";
        break;
    case "APPR":
    case "IACT":
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Inactive";
        break;
    default:
        acctStatusLabel.Text = "Closed";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
switch(acct.acctStatusCode) {
    case "DORM" : acctStatusLabel.Text = "Dormant"; break;
    case "APPR" : case "IACT" : acctStatusLabel.Text = "Inactive"; break;
    default : acctStatusLabel.Text = "Closed"; break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just do

```
if status =="xxxx"
   text="XXXX"
else if status == "yyy"
   text = "YYY"
else 
   text = "QQQ"
```

I know this is not the exact code. I mean I suggest stop trying to do overly clever flows with ? and : etc